# Display contents of TSQL view

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a view which if i try to edit, MS SQL Server Management Studio crashes (the view contains a pivot function).

Is there a way i can view the sql that is inside the view without crashing MS SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRY:

```
exec sp_helptext yourViewName
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this query - work on SQL Server 2005 and up:

```
SELECT
    v.name ,
    m.definition 
FROM 
    sys.views v
INNER JOIN 
    sys.sql_modules m ON v.object_id = m.object_id
```

Comment: @KM: yes, sure - for a single view. Otherwise you'll get all views

Answer (score 1):

What version of SQL Management Studio?

In 2008 I do the following:

Right click on the view

Select "Script view as..."

"Create to..." or "Alter to..."

"New query window"

Answer (score 0):

Found it, right click, Create to, Clipboard...